# Removing unevaluated elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, data

I have a large data set that I am calculating, and some elements do not return a value (meaning it does not exist and is valid, but returns a blank list that cannot be further evaluated in the module).

Here is a very small portion of the data.

```
data = 
  {{150, 5, 0.1, 1, {156751/500, 0}}, 
   {150, 5, 2., 1, {1/100 (20343 + (57 First[{}])/5), 57}}, 
   {150, 50, 0.1, 1, {154217/500, 0}}, {150, 50, 2., 1, {78353/250, 0}}}
```

As you can see, one of the elements could not complete the evaluation, and returns a First[{}]. What I want to do is identify all cases where this takes place (they are not identical) and replace them with a constant number, say 290.

The data set I am calculating is massive and I cannot effectively remove these through breaking up the evaluation around these points.

The extra level in the 5 position in each second-level sub-element lists the desired return value and how many data points had to be thrown out that did not meet a specific condition (i.e., statistical fluctuations resulted in false triggers of the critical level). This is important to identify how robust the result is for the other parameters listed in positions 1 through 4 in each second level of data.

I have tried various things, but I cannot find how to identify elements of a list that are not real (can do positive, negative, etc. as shown below).

```
x = {3, 4}
xx = {3, 4, p}
x /. x_?Positive -> 0
xx /. x_?NumericQ -> 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole number, with 290, or just the First[{}]?

Comment: For one, you should be aware that `First` has a second argument that specifies a default. For example, `First[{}]` does not evaluate, but `First[{}, "Error"]` gives `"Error"`. This could be useful for you here. For example, you could use `First[..., Nothing]`, to automatically make elements where `First` doesn't work disappear.

Comment: @Kuba @Sjoerd. Here is part of the code in the Module I am using (too many characters to include it all). `res[[k]] = First[Flatten[Position[zmov*MovingAverage[Table[Log[(okrate + ksinb)/ksinb] ntotal[[i]] - (okrate), {i,1, Length[Testsprt]}], zmov], val_ /; val > a]]]/div + (zmov - 1)/div]; pez = {Mean[DeleteCases[res[[All]], x_ /; x < 300]], Length[DeleteCases[res[[All]], x_ /; x > 300]]};pez`.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks. I should have looked at the input options of First more closely. In some cases the threshold was never reached, so position returned an empty list, and therefore we got `First[{}]`. By placing `First[expr,290]` I got what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @ProfessorL consider adding working example to the question and then self answering with fixes that fit your needs.